# How should I define the reward function for the Connect Four game?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, ai-design, markov-decision-process, rewards

I'm creating an RL application for the game Connect Four. I've researched the different strategies for the game and which positions are more favourable to lead to a win.

Should I be assigning greater rewards when the application places a token in those particular positions? If so, that would mean the application/algorithm is a Connect Four specific application, and not generic?